# Regex for email (shouldn't match string after ; )

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex:  /(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+.[^\s,]+\s?;)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+.[^\s,]+)/g

Could you tell me why it matches this string: "hNw6B@90.com;tesr"
and doesn't match this one: "hNw6B@90.com; test" ?

It shouldn't match the first string. However if there is a valid email after the ; like test@abv.bg, it should be matched.

I will be very grateful if you could help me out.

Comment: There is an obvious difference between the two strings: one space after the semi-colon. The regex does not provide for an optional space after semi-colon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Why not try something like `/\w+@\w+.\w+/g`

Comment: Are looking for semi-colon separated emails string validation? `^[^@\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+(?:\s*;\s*[^@\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+)*$`? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWAYSG/1), are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers @WiktorStribiżew and aerial301.  Wiktor, I used your regex- it works fine, but could you tell me what can I change, so that it matches: hNw6B@90.com; hNw6B@90.com;  
                                     hNw6B@90.com;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^[^@\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+(?:\s*;\s*[^@\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+)*;?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWAYSG/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^@\s;]+` - zero or more chars other than `@`, whitespace and `;`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `[^\s;]+` - zero or more chars other than whitespace and `;`
- `\.` - a dot
- `[^\s;]+` - zero or more chars other than whitespace and `;`
- `(?:\s*;\s*[^@\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+)*` - zero or more repetition of a `;` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces, and then the same pattern as above
- `;?` - an optional `;`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your effort!

Comment: Hello again! Do you have any ideas what should I change so that the expression is still valid if I add a whitespace after ;  in: hNw6B@90.com;

Comment: @ObiGonz If you need to allow optional whitespaces add `\s*` in those places. Look: `^[^@\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+(?:\s*;\s*[^@\s;]+@[^\s;]+\.[^\s;]+)*;?\s*$` allows trailing whitespace.